# How to make first row and all columns transparent in css?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

How to write code for this using HTML and CSS.
[image: Table]

**Please note that first row and columns in first row are transparent**

Comment: Please show what your tried. Stack Overflow is _NOT_ a request site. Consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    height: 6rem;
    width: 6rem;
    text-align: left;
}

.background {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

tr {
    height: 6rem;
    width: 6rem;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="background">
        <td>9</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
```